# Maximal chain in the collection of all invariant subspaces for compact operator $K$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space over ${\Bbb C}$, and $K\in K(X)$ ($K(X) = $ compact operators space). Show that if ${\cal L}$ is a maximal chain in the $Lat K$ ($Lat K = $ the collection of all invariant subspaces for $K$), then ${\cal L}$ is a maximal chain in the lattice of all subspaces of $X$.

I do not have any idea about it. Please give me a hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Let $L$ not be a maximal chain in the lattice of all subspaces of $X$.
 $M \notin $ Lat K for some M subspace of X, i.e. $Kx \notin M$ for some $x \in M$. 

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence in $M$ such that tends to $x$ in $M$ weakly. By Prop. VI.3.3 [A course in Functional Analysis, John B. Conway] $K$ is completely cont., so that $\{ K{x_n}\}$ converges in norm to $Kx \in M$; this contradicts that $Kx \in M$.

Comment: Why not take $x_n=x$ for all $n$? I think you have applied Conway's result wrongly.

Comment: See this for another proof: 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3828064